# Creating a QList from a plain array

Tags: c++, qt

I have this

```
Struct values[] = {
  { a, b },
  { c, d }
};
```

And I just want to create a `QList` out of it

```
QList<Struct> ql(values + 0, values + 2);
```

But for some reason, `QList` has no suitable constructor and seemingly no suitable `insert` function. How does this work? I'm on Qt4.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution would be to first create an `std::list` and then convert that into a `QList`:

```
QList<Struct> ql = 
    QList<Struct>::fromStdList(std::list<Struct>(values + 0, values + 2));
```

However, that would incurs two copies of the array content instead of just one.

The other solution is to use `std::copy` along with a `back_inserter`:

```
QList<Struct> ql;
ql.reserve(2);
std::copy(values + 0, values + 2, std::back_inserter(ql));
```

If you use an array just to have an easy way to initialize the `QList`, you could perhaps use the insertion operator instead (assuming `Struct` defines the proper constructor):

```
QList<Struct> ql;
ql << Struct(a, b)
   << Struct(c, d);
```

Comment: First I wanted to use an array of int as an example, but I figured someone would recommend `q1 << 1 << 2`, so I took the aggregate initialization example :) Thanks, the `std::copy` was spot-on, I'll do that!

Answer (score 2):

Use [fromStdList()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlist.html#fromStdList) static member function as:

```
std::list<Struct> stdList(values + 0, values + 2);
QList<Struct> ql = QList<Struct>::fromStdList(stdList);
```

Or just in one line:

```
QList<Struct> ql = QList<Struct>::fromStdList(std::list<Struct>(values + 0, values + 2));
```

Comment: Thanks. That's just horrible :)